# How to hide wrapped element using v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to hide radio-group element on my code using v-if?

i gave v-if to radio tag it's work, but the radio-group tag is still there, 
i also gave v-if to radio-group tag but property of size is not found,

```
<radio-group v-model="selectedsize">
    <radio v-bind:value="s" v-for="s in size" :key="s.id" v-if="s.size">
        {{ s.size }}
    </radio>
</radio-group>
```

the problem is i dont want to lose radio-group
i want to hide the wrapper from radio-group if size is null on my property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could determine if any of the elements in `size` have a corresponding `size` and then show it if any exist, or hide if none exist.

```
v-if="size.filter((s) => s.size).length">
```